# Using INDIRECT() in sheet reference range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

I have a separate sheet with some data where a user's input will reference the row number of a sheet. I'm trying to reference that sheet by inserting the column letter and taking a number input from a cell to make up the row #.

I've tried:

> =Sheet2!INDIRECT("A"&A1)

where A1 in the current sheet holds a value of 2, thus I want it to obtain

> =Sheet2!A2

The formula returns #ERROR (error - parse error)

How (if possible) can I reference it in that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out... took me a while...

INDIRECT() has to wrap the entire reference. In order to achieve what I needed, the formula looked like this:

> =INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"&A1)

Comment: If you want to learn more about using Indirect you can check this tutorial: http://spreadsheetpro.net/how-to-make-a-dynamic-reference-to-a-worksheet-in-excel-and-google-spreadsheets/ (Jacob put the extra explanation link in this answer's comments)